# Cox proportional hazards model formulation with two correlated covariates

Tags: cox-model, multicollinearity

I want to set up a Cox proportional hazards model with two correlated covariates $x$ and $y$.
The two covariates are defined as this in R:

```
x <- rexp(n)
y <- 2x + rnorm(n)
```

Does the hazard function look like this:

$h(t|x) = h_0(t)\times e^{\beta_1x+\beta_2y}$ or $h(t|x) = h_0(t)\times e^{\beta_1x+\beta_2y+\beta_1\beta_2xy}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how you want to model survival: with `x` and `y` independently associated with outcome (although they are correlated) or if you want their product (interaction) also to be associated with outcome. In other words: do you want the effect of `x` on outcome to depend on the value of `y` (and vice-versa) or not?

For the simple no-interaction situation, your first formula is correct.

An interaction would most generally be modeled as

$$h(t|x) = h_0(t)\times e^{\beta_1x+\beta_2y+\beta_3 xy}.$$

If you are simulating data and want to define $\beta_3=\beta_1 \beta_2$ exactly, your second formula would be OK. If you are fitting a model with an interaction to data, then the above form is what is assumed: $\beta_3$ is modeled separately from either of $\beta_1$ or $\beta_2$.